# Best practices for line breaking in python on method declarations and long lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a recent code review, it was mentioned that it is better to break parameters for **init** and other methods onto their own lines because it is easier to read. I have never seen this before and was wondering if this is the pythonic way to handle this scenario.

**Parameters on separate lines**

```
 def __init__(
        self,
        name: str = '',
        address: str = '',
        license: str = '',
        job_title: str = '',
        notes: str = '',
        gender: Gender = None,
        status: Status = None
):
```

**Parameters on the same line**

```
def __init__(self, name: str = '', address: str = '', license: str = ''
             job_title: str = '', notes: str = '', 
             gender: Gender = None, status: Status = None):
```

Following this same pattern, it was also recommended to break up long lists or dictionaries in the same way.

**List values on separate lines**

```
countries = [
    Belgium,
    Canada,
    Denmark,
    Ethiopia,
    France, 
    Germany, 
    Haiti, 
    Italy,
    Japan,
    Korea,
    Lebanon
]
```

**List values on the same lines**

```
countries = [Belgium, Canada, Denmark, Ethiopia, France, Germany,     
             Haiti, Italy, Japan, Korea, Lebanon]
```

Comment: [*PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) provides useful guidelines

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The PEP doesn't specify one way or the other. It's examples seem to reference having the parameters on the same line only breaking when necessary, but both are technically valid. I'm just wondering what people actually use in their day to day?

Comment: In addition to readability, maintainability is easier too. You can simply delete a line when deleting a parameter or insert a new line for additional parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is any **officially** recognized preference here (other than that lines shouldn't go over X characters -- where X = 80 if you're following [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).  Different projects may have different preferences (or no preference) in this area ...

As one point of reference, `pylint` accepts either of those as valid I think...

My personal preference is to flow the arguments vertically when they don't all fit on one line.

I think that the best "general" advice that I can give you is to try to be consistent with the surrounding code.  If you are the first author and the project doesn't have any guidelines, do what you find to be most comfortable.

Comment: This very helpful. Thank you! I will be modifying my code to flow the arguments vertically. It just takes some getting used to when looking at it visually.